# Is it possible to get it done with 1 sql query, not with 30?

Tags: php, sql

**I have to count all rows for the last 30 days** for a google graph, but the only solution that actually works for me is getting it done one by one, witch is a bit slow. **Is it possible to do it with one query, if yes, how?**

I have already tried with COUNT, SUM, DATEDIFF, etc. but I can not get it to work.

```
for ($i = 30; $i >= 1; $i--) {
  $date = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
  date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("- ".$i." days"));
  $date = date_format($date, "Y-m-d"); 

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as views FROM views INNER JOIN maps ON maps.id = views.mapid WHERE maps.userid = ? AND views.date = ?");

  $stmt->bind_param('is', $_SESSION['user_id'], $date);

  $stmt->execute();

  $result = $stmt->get_result();

  $date = date_create($date);
  date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("- 1 month"));
  $date = date_format($date, "Y,  m, d"); 

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)    {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "[new Date(".$date."), ".$row['views']."], ";
  } else {
    echo "[new Date(".$date."), 0], ";
  }

  $stmt->close();
}
```

The output with this code is ok, but as i mentioned i am not to proud with this solution, and also slow as I have to make 5 more google-graph with it.

Comment: What are you trying to get from SQL? Both date and count?

Comment: you can use `>=` to choose a date range.  IE `SELECT COUNT(*) ----- 
 WHERE views.date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )` would pull the `count` for the last month ..  No need for a `php` loop

Comment: Conversely --  You can use `BETWEEN` to get exactly `30 days` back from `today` -- >  `WHERE   views.date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()`

Comment: @EdwinDijasChiwona Yes I need the date and the view count for every days separate like this: [new Date(2019, 05, 22), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 23), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 24), 0], and so on.

Comment: @Zak I need every days view count and date separate like this: [new Date(2019, 05, 22), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 23), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 24), 0], an so on.

Answer (score 1):

No need for complicated date inputs ..  To get the last 30 days simply use `BETWEEN`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as views 
  FROM views 
    INNER JOIN maps 
    ON maps.id = views.mapid 
  WHERE maps.userid = ? 
  AND views.date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW();
```

Remember you will have to remove the date parameter from your prepared statement's `bind` parameter.

Comment: As i see this counts all at once, but i need every day, with zeros as well, like: [new Date(2019, 05, 22), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 23), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 24), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 25), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 26), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 27), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 28), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 29), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 30), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 01), 9], [new Date(2019, 06, 02), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 03), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 04), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 05), 0],.......

Comment: Aahh I see .. Fopr something like this .. You should be using a MySQL procedure with a loop  --  IE [MySQL While Procedure](http://www.w3webtutorial.com/mysql/mysql-loop-statement.php)

Comment: Yes, luckily i did it! :D Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the count by date:

```
SELECT COUNT(views.date) as views, views.date 
  FROM views 
  INNER JOIN maps 
  ON maps.id = views.mapid WHERE maps.userid = ?
  AND views.date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY views.date
```

Comment: This is close, but i also need the dates where the views is 0,

Comment: Your result: [new Date(2019, 06, 01), 9],
[new Date(2019, 06, 09), 3],
[new Date(2019, 06, 15), 11],      Expected: [new Date(2019, 05, 22), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 23), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 24), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 25), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 26), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 27), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 28), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 29), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 30), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 01), 9], [new Date(2019, 06, 02), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 03), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 04), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 05), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 06), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 07), 0],.....

Comment: Read the entire result set into memory, Then loop in PHP: for each date see if it is in the result set. If found, use the view count. If not found, set view count to zero. You are only making one trip to the DB, and your result set is small enough to search. (I don't know php so I can't give the exact syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Easily. Simply adjust the where clause to use >= and <= operators for the date field.

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as views
FROM views
INNER JOIN maps
ON maps.id = views.mapid
WHERE
    maps.userid = ?
AND
    (
        views.date >= CAST('2019-06-01' AS DATE) -- start date
    AND
        views.date <= CAST('2019-06-30' AS DATE) -- end date
    );
```

PS: You can still bind the parameters for the start and end date. I still highly recommend checking out PDO for MySQL. It's relatively native to PHP and this is how you could accomplish this:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbname = 'testdatabase';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'qwerty123';

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $userid = 12345;
    $startdate = '2019-06-01';
    $enddate = '2019-06-30';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as views FROM views INNER JOIN maps ON maps.id = views.mapid WHERE maps.userid = :userid AND ( views.date >= CAST(:startdate AS DATE) AND views.date <= CAST(:enddate AS DATE) );");
    $stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userid);
    $stmt->bindValue(':startdate', $startdate);
    $stmt->bindValue(':enddate', $enddate);

    $stmt->execute();
    $rowcount = $stmt->rowCount();

    echo "$rowcount records found!";
?>
```

**Note**: You *can* use the "BETWEEN" op in SQL however, I personally like to cast because it's clean and easy. It's really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

With the helpful answers and comments, i created the solution!
Thanks for all of the help!

**The working solution:**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(views.date) as views, views.date 
    FROM views 
    INNER JOIN maps 
    ON maps.id = views.mapid WHERE maps.userid = ?
    AND views.date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
    GROUP BY views.date");

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['user_id']);

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        for ($i = 30; $i >= 0; $i--) {
          $date = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
          date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("- ".$i." days"));
          $date = date_format($date, "Y-m-d"); 
          $graphdate = date_create($date);
          date_add($graphdate, date_interval_create_from_date_string("- 1 month"));
          $graphdate = date_format($graphdate, "Y,  m, d"); 

          if ($row['date'] == $date) {
            if ($i == 0) {
              echo "[new Date(".$graphdate."), ".$row['views']."] ";
            } else {
              echo "[new Date(".$graphdate."), ".$row['views']."], ";
            }
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
          } else {
            if ($i == 0) {
              echo "[new Date(".$graphdate."), 0] ";
            } else {
              echo "[new Date(".$graphdate."), 0], ";
            }
          }
        }
      }

    $stmt->close();
```

Output:

> [new Date(2019, 05, 22), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 23), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 24), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 25), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 26), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 27), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 28), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 29), 0], [new Date(2019, 05, 30), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 01), 9], [new Date(2019, 06, 02), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 03), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 04), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 05), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 06), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 07), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 08), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 09), 3], [new Date(2019, 06, 10), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 11), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 12), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 13), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 14), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 15), 11], [new Date(2019, 06, 16), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 17), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 18), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 19), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 20), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 21), 0], [new Date(2019, 06, 22), 2]